# For loop is not working with json data

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to make a loop in javascript with the following code. It's getting length from json data.
The `console.log(albums.data.length);` line is working and returning 3. Why the loop is not working then?
The `console.log(x);` is not returning anything, even not blank line.
There is also no error in console.

```
function getBestPhoto(albums){
    console.log(albums);
    console.log(albums.data.length);
    for(var x in albums.data.length){
        console.log(x);
        for(var y in albums.data[x].photos.length){
            console.log(y);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried another type of loop(`for(var i = 0; i < blabla; i++)`) but its not working too.

Edit:
I wanna use
 `for(var x = 0; x < albums.data.length; x++){
            console.log(albums.data[x].photos.id);
        }`
instead of

```
for(var x in albums.data){
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-in loop is not for arrays, it is for iterating over properties/fields of an object. If `albums.data` is an array, you should use the `forEach` loop statement instead. If `albums.data` is an object, and you are trying to access its properties/fields/attributes, you can use the `for-in` construct.

If `albums.data` is an array, try:

```
albums.data.forEach(function(element, index) {
  // Here you have access to each element (object) of the "albums.data" array
  console.log(element.toString());
  // You can also access each element's properties/fields if the element is an 
  // object. 
  // If the element is an array itself, you need to iterate over its elements 
  // in another inner foreach. 
  // Here we are accessing the "photos" property of each element - which itself
  // is another array.
  element.photos.forEach(function(photo, index) {
    // Here you have access to the elements of the "photos" array 
    // Each element of the "photos" array is put in the photo variable. 
    // Assuming each element of the "photos" array is an object, you can access 
    // its properties, using the dot notation:
    console.log("photo id=", photo.id);
    // If the property name (e.g. "id") is not a valid javascript name 
    // (has some special symbols), use the bracket notation
    console.log("photo URL=", photo["photo-url"]);
  });
});
```

You can also use the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) library for this (and many other neat functionalities).

If `albums.data` is an object, try:

```
for (var prop in albums.data) {
  // Again, this construct is for accessing properties of an object 
  // (e.g. if albums.data is an object), not an array.
  console.log("property name=" + prop + ", " + "property value=" +
              albums.data[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `.length` from loops

```
function getBestPhoto(albums){
    console.log(albums);
    console.log(albums.data.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < albums.data.length; i++){
        var x = albums.data[i];
        console.log(x);
        for(var j = 0; j < albums.data[i].photos.length; j++){
            var y = albums.data[i].photos[j];
            console.log(y);
            console.log(albums.data[i].photos[j].id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you check the thread again? i have changed my mind about how i wanna do it. Thanks for you response.

Comment: i updated my code after your edit. added console.log(albums.data[i].photos[j].id);

Comment: the first loop is working now, but the second isn't. I get error in the console: TypeError: albums.data[i].photos is undefined

Comment: what is your "albums" object hierarchy? what kind of variables and arrays it have?